# Javascript Recurse JSON array with children objects

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

Is there a way to recurse the following JSON without for-looping the nested children?

My recursive function must be missing a case as it's not returning everything.

```
iterateTree(node, children) {
    console.log(node.name)

    if(node.children.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      var child_node = children[i];

      return this.iterateTree(child_node, child_node.children);
    }
  }

for(var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
      var node = sample[i];
      this.iterateTree(node, node.children);
    }

var sample = [
  {
    "name": "hello world",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "fruits",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "vegetables",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "meats",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "pork",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "beef",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "chicken",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "organic",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "farm raised",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "second folder",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "third folder",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "breads",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "coffee",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "latte",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "cappucino",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "mocha",
            "children": []
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Aiming to achieve the following output (similiar to file structure)

```
hello world
-fruits
-vegetables
-meats 
--pork
--beef
--chicken
---organic
---farm raised
second folder
third folder
-breads
-coffee
--latte
--cappucino
--mocha
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet for verification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create recursive function using `reduce` method to iterate through your nested data structure, return array and then use `join` method on that array.

```js
var sample = [{"name":"hello world","children":[{"name":"fruits","children":[]},{"name":"vegetables","children":[]},{"name":"meats","children":[{"name":"pork","children":[]},{"name":"beef","children":[]},{"name":"chicken","children":[{"name":"organic","children":[]},{"name":"farm raised","children":[]}]}]}]},{"name":"second folder","children":[]},{"name":"third folder","children":[{"name":"breads","children":[]},{"name":"coffee","children":[{"name":"latte","children":[]},{"name":"cappucino","children":[]},{"name":"mocha","children":[]}]}]}]

function tree(data, prev = '') {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    r.push(prev + e.name)
    if (e.children.length) r.push(...tree(e.children, prev + '-'));
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = tree(sample).join('\n')
console.log(result)
```

To create same structure in HTML you could use `forEach` method instead.

```js
var sample = [{"name":"hello world","children":[{"name":"fruits","children":[]},{"name":"vegetables","children":[]},{"name":"meats","children":[{"name":"pork","children":[]},{"name":"beef","children":[]},{"name":"chicken","children":[{"name":"organic","children":[]},{"name":"farm raised","children":[]}]}]}]},{"name":"second folder","children":[]},{"name":"third folder","children":[{"name":"breads","children":[]},{"name":"coffee","children":[{"name":"latte","children":[]},{"name":"cappucino","children":[]},{"name":"mocha","children":[]}]}]}]

function tree(data, parent) {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  data.forEach(el => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = el.name;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    if (el.children.length) {
      tree(el.children, li)
    }
  })
  parent.appendChild(ul)
}

const parent = document.getElementById('root')
tree(sample, parent)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is an impressive function. However what if you wanted to output nested <ul><li></li></ul> combination instead of purely text dash (-).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sample = [{"name":"hello world","children":[{"name":"fruits","children":[]},{"name":"vegetables","children":[]},{"name":"meats","children":[{"name":"pork","children":[]},{"name":"beef","children":[]},{"name":"chicken","children":[{"name":"organic","children":[]},{"name":"farm raised","children":[]}]}]}]},{"name":"second folder","children":[]},{"name":"third folder","children":[{"name":"breads","children":[]},{"name":"coffee","children":[{"name":"latte","children":[]},{"name":"cappucino","children":[]},{"name":"mocha","children":[]}]}]}]

  level = 0;
  var hyphens = '';

  function recursive_loop(s) {  
    console.log(hyphens + s.name);
    var c = s.children;
    if (c.length) hyphens += '-';
    var empty = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      if (c[i].children) {
        recursive_loop(c[i]);
      }
      if (c[i].children.length)
        empty = true;
    }
    if (empty) hyphens = '';
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
    recursive_loop(sample[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) foe many data processing / traversal tasks. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you could solve your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const display = (input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  reverse: false,
  rtn: 'entry',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => typeof value === 'string'
})(input)
  .map(([k, v]) => `${'-'.repeat(k.length / 2 - 1)}${v}`);

const sample = [{ name: 'hello world', children: [{ name: 'fruits', children: [] }, { name: 'vegetables', children: [] }, { name: 'meats', children: [{ name: 'pork', children: [] }, { name: 'beef', children: [] }, { name: 'chicken', children: [{ name: 'organic', children: [] }, { name: 'farm raised', children: [] }] }] }] }, { name: 'second folder', children: [] }, { name: 'third folder', children: [{ name: 'breads', children: [] }, { name: 'coffee', children: [{ name: 'latte', children: [] }, { name: 'cappucino', children: [] }, { name: 'mocha', children: [] }] }] }];

const result = display(sample);
result.forEach((l) => console.log(l));
// => hello world
// => -fruits
// => -vegetables
// => -meats
// => --pork
// => --beef
// => --chicken
// => ---organic
// => ---farm raised
// => second folder
// => third folder
// => -breads
// => -coffee
// => --latte
// => --cappucino
// => --mocha
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)